Getting symbolic sum from a[k]
My Goal is to get summation from definition a[k] as below. I tried simple arithmetic progression 1,2,3,4,5.. . Although the function Sum returns symbolic result nicely, but my code doesn't. How to fix to get symbolic result to get 1/2 n (n+1) from a[k] definition?
Sum[i,{i,1,n}] (*1/2 n (n+1) *)(* Sum returns symbolic result*)

a[1]=1;
a[k_Integer?Positive]:=a[k-1]+1    (*definition of arithmetic progression *)
Assuming[Element[{k,n},Integers],Sum[a[k],{k,1,n}]]  (*How to fix to get symbolic result 1/2 n (n+1*)


But these do not give same result? did you check? here is screen shot  https://i.sstatic.net/H3JZn7hO.png  i,e, for same n they do not give same value as the Sum.

I think you need a[1]=1;  a[k_Integer?Positive]:=k+a[k-1]; and now they give same results for each n  https://i.sstatic.net/A26q79F8.png   You can also do a[k_Integer?Positive] := a[k] = k + a[k - 1]; to speed it up.

You can  use RSolve, e.g.:
f[n_, k_] := 
 Simplify[
  a[n] /. RSolve[{a[n] == a[n - 1] + n^k, a[1] == 1}, a, n][[1]]]

Some cases:
Grid[Table[{j, 
   StringForm[
    "\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \
\(n\)]\)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(i\), \(``\)]\)", j], f[n, j]}, {j, 0, 
   4}], Frame -> All]



Thank you for your answer. After getting a[n] with RSolve, then using known fact Sum[n,{n,1,n}],then the sum of a[n] arrived. (※The merit of RSolve seems to be that no numerical sample data is needed. I guess some sort of telecoping technique might be used without using fitting technique.)

This gets you what you want in a work around way
a[1] = 1;
a[k_Integer?Positive] := a[k] = k + a[k - 1];
FindFormula[Table[a[i], {i, 1, 10}], n] // Rationalize // Simplify


I do not know why
a[1] = 1;
a[k_Integer?Positive] := a[k] = k + a[k - 1];
Assuming[Element[{k, n}, Integers] && n > 1, Sum[a[k], {k, 1, n}]]

Gives


Using FindSequenceFunction
$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

a[1] = 1;
a[k_Integer?Positive] := a[k] = a[k - 1] + 1

sum[n_Integer?Positive] := sum[n] = Sum[a[k], {k, 1, n}]

seq = sum /@ Range[5]

(* {1, 3, 6, 10, 15} *)

FindSequenceFunction[seq, n]

(* 1/2 n (1 + n) *)

Checking,

% === Sum[k, {k, 1, n}]

(* True *)

